# BX Slider - startSlide option

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm using bx-slider as a navigation menu.

In each slide I'm displaying 4 items and I don't know how to use `startSlide` option so that bx-slider would not start on first slide but rather with the slide in which contains a clicked item.

For example:

1. Item 1  |  Item 2  | item 3  | Item 4
2. Item 5  |  Item 6  | item 7  | Item 8
3. Item 9  |  Item 10 | item 11  | Item 12

If I click on item 7, I'd like that a starting slide would be slide 2, not one. I don't know how to use `startSlide` since I have 4 items in one slide.

This is the code I use:

```
$('.slider').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 220,
        auto: false,
        pause: 5000,
        minSlides: 4,
        nextText: '',
        prevText: '',
        maxSlides: 4,
        slideMargin: 20,
        pager:false
    });
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: here's my menu code:

```
<ul class="slider_items">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post your menu's markup so we can provide better feedback

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a class on your active navigation menu.

I'm assuming your menu is structured as follows

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><!-- .closest li -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="active">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 10</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 11</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can then add the `startSlide` option to bxSlider as follows:

```
var startSlide = $('.active').closest('li').index()
```